App sheet function of calculate vacation days
How to calculate function that get remining days from vacation and minus them from 21 days also included week end days by app sheet
I try round function and it removes from 21 days but when the employee another request it is still minus from 21 days, not the remaining days

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
